# jsonp data showing invalid label error

Tags: dojo, jsonp

From other posts I figured that this error just means my remote server is not returning my results in jsonp but rather just the json it is in.

```
{"rules":[{"value":"AllState"},{"value":"Cidade de Goa beach"},
    {"value":"Euro 2012"},{"value":"Euro&2012"},
    {"value":"Euro2012"},{"value":"European&Championship"},
    {"value":"Holiday Inn Resort"}]}
```

Now I was told include the callback parameter etc. but this just does not work. I do not know of any other way to get my data from the server other than a web service all from my web application with dojo widgets. How do I enable the server to return jsonp or can I change the webservice to do this which I created as WCF service in visual studio 2010.

```
 function search() {
     var targetNode = dojo.byId("rules");
     var jsonpArgs = {
        //url: "https://webservceexmaple.com/data_collectors/4/rules.json",
        jsonp: "jsonp",
        headers:{'X-Requested-With': null},
        content: {
            screenName: "testing"
        },
        load: function (data) {
            targetNode.innerHTML = "<pre>" + dojo.toJson(data, true) + "</pre>";
        },
        error: function (error) {
            targetNode.innerHTML = "An unexpected error occurred: " + error;
        }
    };
    dojo.io.script.get(jsonpArgs);
}
dojo.ready(search);
```

Answer (score 1):

You might find a lot of answers here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg585144.aspx

Implementing a serverside service is not 'just' done, check this http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/sridhar_subra/consuming-wcf-asmx-rest-service-using-jquery/ at c# corner